# Conversion of Oracle query to teradata query

Tags: oracle, teradata

How to convert this below query to equivalent teradate query. I tried but results varies a lot.

```
select il.domainN as listname, il.SourceID, ns.sourcename, cbo.customerid, cu.username, hv.domainN as HTname
,  nvl((select 1 
        from mydb.customerPP cpp 
        where cbo.customerid = cpp.customerid 
          and NOT EXISTS (select 1 from mydb.customerPI cpt where cpp.customerid = cpt.customerid)
          and trunc(cpp.startdate) <= sysdate
        group by cpp.customerid),0) as BBID
from mydb.customerBO cbo
  join mydb.customers cu on cbo.customerid = cu.customerid
  join mydb.inv il on cbo.domainN = il.domainN
  join mydb.Sources ns on il.SourceID = ns.SourceID
  left join mydb2.HT hv on (il.domainN = hv.domainN
                                  and hv.sDate+1 >= il.dDate
                                  and il.dDate+1 >= hv.sDate)
where cbo.customerBOID = 1 
  and cu.statusid = 1
  and il.sourceTID = 2
  and il.joinbydate >= cbo.cDate 
  and trunc(il.dDate) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Thanks.

Comment: @GergelyBacso  i just changed hv.sDate+1 and il.dDate+1 to date+inetrval '1' day and it ran successfully but results are not same. i think there is something else needs to be changed or i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Changing to `<datefield> + INTERVAL '1' DAY` and changing `sysdate` to `CURRENT_DATE` should do the trick. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: @JNevill no still not giving correct results

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce instead nvl and compare explain statements to see whether you have left outer joins converted to inner joins for nvl on Teradata.